# How can I clear a column in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I want to clear all values found in the column range `G2:GX` where `GX` corresponds to the last cell that is not empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at [Range.clear() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear()):

```
function clearColumn(colNumber, startRow){
  //colNumber is the numeric value of the colum
  //startRow is the number of the starting row

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - startRow + 1; // The number of row to clear
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, colNumber, numRows);
  range.clear();

}
```

or if you want to keep the A1 notation:

```
function clearColumnA1Notation(a1Notation){
  //a1Notation is the A1 notation of the  first element of the column

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstCell = sheet.getRange(a1Notation);
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - firstCell.getRow() + 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstCell.getRow(), firstCell.getColumn(), numRows);
  range.clear();

}
```

For your example, you can use:

```
clearColumn(7, 2);
```

or

```
clearColumnA1Notation("G2");
```

Comment: It's not a big deal, but `sheet,getLastRow()` is getting the last row for the entire sheet, not the column, so some cells get cleared that don't need to be.

Comment: This clears more than values. From what I can tell it also removes formatting.

Comment: @AnnanFay To only clear values you can use range.clearContent()

Answer (score 5):

sheet.getRange("G1:G").clear();

This syntax will clear a column from G1 to last available G Column value. if you want to clear it from between like from 3rd row, then you can use

sheet.getRange("G3:G").clear();